# jsmart - Can't get template contents (in time?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smarty, templating

I'm trying to use [jsmart](http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/) to render [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)3 templates on the client-side.  If you've no experience with them, keep reading because it could just be a simple JavaScript error that I'm making.

---

#### It works for simple templates:

I create the template (which I receive via AJAX), then render it (passing it the data), as per the documentation:

```
var template = new jSmart(templateReceivedViaAJAX);
var content = template.fetch({"firstname":"adam", "secondname":"lynch"});
```

Then I simply stick the rendered output in a `div`:

```
$('#dest').html(content);
```

---

#### Template inheritance

Problems happen when trying to render templates which contain `include`, `extends`, etc.

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/wiki/IncludeTemplates):

> Whenever jSmart come across either of template inclusion tags it calls jSmart.prototype.getTemplate() method and passes it a value of tag's file parameter. The method must return the template's text.
>
> The default implementation of getTemplate() throws an exception. So, it is up to a jSmart user to override this method and provide template's text.

---

#### Overridding the `getTemplate()` function:

```
jSmart.prototype.getTemplate = function(name) {
    $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: name, async:false, success: function(data) {
        console.log('got template at '+name+'. The following is the contents:');
        console.debug(data);
                
        return data;
    }});
}
```

---

#### The console output when rendering a *parent* template containing an `include` call to a *child* template:

```
<div class="row">

    <label for="second" class="span4">Second Name:</label>  

    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="{$secondname}" id="second" /> 

</div>

<p>B;lsdsfasfsfds</p>
Uncaught Error: No template for /bundles/templatedemo/templates/form_include.html.smarty
```

---

#### The console output when rendering a *child* template containing an `extend` call to a *parent* template:

```
got template at /bundles/templatedemo/templates/form.html.smarty. The following is the contents: templates:58
<form class="well">  

    <div class="row">

        <label for="first" class="span4">First Name:</label>  

        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="{$firstname}" id="first" /> 

    </div>

    {block name=form_include}{/block}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" />  

</form>
Uncaught Error: No template for /bundles/templatedemo/templates/form.html.smarty 
(expanded:)
S 
(anonymous function) 
jSmart.fetch 
(anonymous function) 
f.event.dispatch 
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

---

#### Edit:

Inheritance works if the template contents are there in advance (if they're hard-coded in, instead of being retrieved via AJAX, for example).

Comment: I'll try to test jSmart against SmartyBundle later, tonight (GMT) to see if this is SmartyBundle related. I'm also available on the `#noiselabs` freenode channel if you want to debug it live.

Comment: @noisebleed Thanks! I'll be there all day (GMT+1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a function pointer rather than an anonymous function:

```
function foo() 
  {
  $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: foo.url, async:false, success: bar});
  }

function bar(data) 
  {
  console.log(['got template at', foo.url, 'The following is the contents:']);
  console.debug(data);

  return data;
  }

foo.url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

jSmart.prototype.getTemplate = foo;
```