# JQMobile - unable to load spinner in custom ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a search form that is **data-ajax=false**. As i want to write my own custom ajax call.

```
<form id="search" data-ajax="false">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
<input required="required" autocorrect="off" name="TERM_1" placeholder="Search Catalogue" type="search" value=""/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Below is the js code

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function() {
$('#search').unbind('submit');
        $('#search').submit(function(event) {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', { text: "loading", textonly: true, textVisible : true });
        input = $('[name="TERM_1"]').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: 'LiberoWebServices.JSONAPI.cls',
            data: 
            {
                Method: "Catalogue",
                Type: "simple",
                Split: 10,
                Term: input
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                loadResults(data);
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
            }
        })
        return false;
        });
    });
```

The loading popup doesn't seem to show. I'm guessing it has to do with the way i unbind and bind.
The reason i unbinded it was because everytime i submit the form it keeps running the ajax call for all the other pages i have pre-fetched in my DOM.
I'm not sure what's the best way to go about doing this.

Need help figuring out how to get the loading popup to show.
Thanks

Comment: You should do things step by step. I guess you verified that unbinding works. Next verify that your binding is being invoked with random testJS like alert/log. Then verify that the loading('show') works.. (on itself). Then everything coming together should work as well. I'm wondering if the submit itself prevents the attached JS from occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Use a change in the logic. Instead of this:

```
 $('#search').unbind('submit');
```

create a function pointer and reset the binding to run it once, as in these unrelated questions:

- [jsmart - Can't get template contents (in time?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739922/jsmart-cant-get-template-contents-in-time/19736295#19736295)
- [How to Run a Greasemonkey Script only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249703/how-to-run-a-greasemonkey-script-only-once/15847401#15847401)