# How to Run a Greasemonkey Script only once

Tags: greasemonkey

I made a greasemonkey script for a domain, Now how do I make it run only once? Like it starts every time the domain is accessed, I don't want that. How do I make it run only once and then like delete itself or make itself inactive?

Thanks.

Comment: I want my visitor to be redirected to a welcome page only on his first visit explaining him the terms of conditions and privacy policies. I wouldn't want them to go that page on every visit. :)

Comment: So you are the maintainer of the page. No need to use Greasemonkey.
Are they logged users ? Add it to the sign in page.
Aren't they ? Can't be accurate, but you may use cookies and put the expire date to years later

Comment: A Greasemonkey script runs on the client side, so you'd have to get all of your visitors to install the script.

Comment: I know how to do it with PHP, Not sure how I can do that with Greasemonkey. Any help?

Comment: Did you read the comments above? Greasemonkey is unlikely to be the right choice here - every one of your users would have to have it (and your script) installed

Comment: Yes, I know.. But this is not a commercial choice. I am testing this out so that I can learn. Its like a case study.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a script (or part of a script) to run only once, then you need to store a flag in non-volatile storage.  A script cannot delete itself or turn itself off.  But it can exit right away rather than run any other code.

To store things on a site-by-site (domain) basis, use [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/331508).  To store things on a script+namespace basis, use [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).  Here's a basic script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Run a GM script one-time only
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

var alreadyRun = GM_getValue ("alreadyRun",  false);

if ( ! alreadyRun) {
    GM_setValue ("alreadyRun", true);
    alert ("This part of the script will run exactly once per install.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the function as the last statement in the body:

```
function foo()
 {
 ...
 foo = function(){};
 }
```